# Stopping the application will Clear the cache?

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis

I have one asp.net application and stored some values(like user name and password) in server side cache. If I stop the application from the IIS, does data stored in cache will exist or loss?

Comment: will be loss, if your cache is not base on a database but on memory. Why dont you make a test ?

Comment: You should be more specific, when you say "Clear the Cache" what do you mean by that? Are you talking about session state? Are you talking about using the system.web.caching objects?